# Apple Mach-O Linker Error / Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

Tags: ios, xcode, linker-errors, undefined-symbol

So I've searched all throughout the web for an answer of this problem, but no luck. Ive been working on this project without any issues, then one day i started getting these errors (see image below). I know a lot of people have had this same issue and it seems to be a 'magical' error with a 'magical' solution. If you could offer any insight or require more information. Please help.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The architecture i386 is the architecture for a simulator (ARM is the architecture for the iPhone).  If you ran this code on your iPhone it would likely work. I would try the following possible solutions.

1. Press command + shift + k to clear data that xcode stores.  Maybe something just got saved oddly.
2. The issue could be that you are compiling for the 64-bit simulator when one of your frameworks you are using does not support that.  Try compiling for the regular simulator.
3. It could be that you possibly downloaded a version of the frameworks that does not have that architecture installed (which seems somewhat unlikely).  Try removing first the MQMapKit it just to see if the error goes away.  Try re-downloading them and then installing them to see if the issue goes away.